# Form1 controls and threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, listview

Right now, the line of code I'm worrying about looks like this:

```
listView1.Items.Add(additional + message, icon);
```

Works fine, but only in Form1 of course. What do I need to do if I want to use the Add() method of my Listview from another class? (Multithreading 'n stuff.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a  method on your form:

```
    public void AddMessageAsync(string message, int icon)
    {
        Action<string, int> handler = (aMessage, imageIndex) =>
            listView1.Items.Add("someMessage" + aMessage, imageIndex);


        BeginInvoke(handler, message, icon);
    }
```

Comment: You have an extra `)` before the `=>` (or a missing `(` before the parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the listview's items from another class is not multi-threading (which would cause other problems on the UI anyway). So, if you want to access the `listView1` from another class, then you need to make the listview object `public`, and you will also need a reference inside of the class you are trying to access it from